# Laravel Pagination when database is empty

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

I have a CRUD system where the administrator can manage users.

The users overview has a pagination function:

```
public function index()
{
    $users = User::first()->paginate(5);
    return view('users.index', compact('users'));
}
```

Which then goes through a `foreach` in my `index.blade.php` file. And this works perfectly.

Untill the Administrator decides to delete all database records. This gives me the following error:

`Call to a member function paginate() on null`

How should I fix this error?
I want it to show the page but just not execute the `Foreach` when there are no results.

Comment: Use `User::paginate(5);` instead, Not sure if you are fluent in english but its clear that you can not paginate anything if you have only **one** record `->first()` gets you the first record (only **one** can be first). For not-executing foreach, you need to have if statement, something like `@if($users->count() > 0) // do foreach // @endif`. Good Luck!

Comment: Of course. Now you say it it does make sence.
English is not my native language, but I do speak it fluently. I just didn't think of it this way. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: No problem, have fun!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove `first()` from query

```
public function index()
{
    $users = User::paginate(5);
    return view('users.index', compact('users'));
}
```